# if-then-else based on command output

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am using netstat command to get information on networks. I want to put a condition here on protocol fetched. If it's TCP, I need to print different columns than if it's UDP.

Below is what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work. Please suggest and advise if there is something I am doing wrong:

```
if [$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}')=="tcp"] then

netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1,",",$4"}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv

elif [$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}')=="udp"] then

netstat -anputw | awk '{print $5,",",$7}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Always leave a space after `[` and before `]` in if statement and you should put command `$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}'`   under double quotes if you are doing string comparison.

Here's the final script:

```
if [ "$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}')" == "tcp" ]; then

netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1,",",$4"}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv

elif [ "$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}') " == "udp" ]; then

netstat -anputw | awk '{print $5,",",$7}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, however I think that netstat returns a list rather than a string, therefore comparing the output against a string is pointless. You have to loop it. Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=$(netstat -anputw | awk '{print $1}');

for LINE in $OUTPUT
do
    if [[ $LINE == "tcp" ]] ; then
        echo "TCP!"
    elif [[ $LINE == "udp" ]] ; then
        echo "UDP!"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate the two cases by not asking `netstat` to mix them up?

```
netstat -anptw   # Just tcp
netstat -anpuw   # Just udp
```

Also, in the tcp case, you don't seem to care about the `-p` information so you might as well not ask for it. And in the udp case, there is no data in the State column, so the PID/Program name will actually be in column 6.

Putting that together, I get:

```
netstat -antw | awk '{print $1","$4}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv
netstat -anpuw | awk '{print $5","$6}' >> $HOME/MyLog/connections_$HOSTNAME.csv
```

I suspect that isn't quite the information you're looking for either, though. Perhaps you want to distinguish between TCP listening and non-listening connections.